# Angular Azure Mobile Service Client API Key Usage

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm looking at using the [Angular Azure Mobile Service Client](https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-azure-mobile-service) for a project, I saw this sample code:

```
 angular.module('your-module-name').constant('AzureMobileServiceClient', {
    API_URL : 'https://<your-api-url>.azure-mobile.net/',
    API_KEY : '<your-api-key>',
  });
```

Is it safe to use the API Key in an AngularJS app like this (or any JavaScript based client)?  I'm unsure what someone could potentially do if they had this key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-call-custom-api/) in the Azure Mobile Services documentation:

> With default permissions, anyone with the app key may call the custom
>   API. However, the application key is not considered a secure
>   credential because it may not be distributed or stored securely.
>   Consider restricting access to only authenticated users for additional
>   security.

Comment: Application key simply is saying your website is authorized as [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.Application)]. But as you can see, people can simply figure out your key and make a API call. So really unless it's a method can be called "anonymously", you probably always want to authorize as an user. For everything else, use application level. Application key can be changed so as Vladimir mentioned. You could change the key to stop some attack. But yeah it's a "gentleman's" way to do a small bit of security.

Answer (score 1):

It is'Safe' depending on what you are trying to do. Javascript and any keys in it can be read by everyone. This is key is not meant to be used as a password to access important information. Instead it is made to prevent malevolent abuse of your application.

For example if someone is trying to log in 1,000 times per second with every possible password/username combination, they are submitting this key with each request. So you could throttle, or block anyone using this key. Then you would issue a new key to your apps. If you have a system for issuing those keys you might even identify the person that was doing it. 
It can stop DDOS, Bruteforce, and some other abuses